# Slow Query crontab shell script

Tags: shell

I have slow query shell script mentioned below:

```
scp kill_slow_queries.sh root@$db:/root/
ssh -t -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$db "grep -q -F '#Chef Name: kill_slow_queries' /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root || echo '#Chef Name: kill_slow_queries' >> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root"
ssh -t -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$db "grep -q -F '* * * * * cd /root && sh kill_slow_queries.sh >> killed_queries.log' /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root || echo ' * * * * * cd /root && sh kill_slow_queries.sh >> killed_queries.log' >> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root"
ssh -t -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$db "grep -q -F '* * * * * ( sleep 15 ; cd /root && sh kill_slow_queries.sh >> killed_queries.log )' /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root || echo ' * * * * * ( sleep 15 ; cd /root && sh kill_slow_queries.sh >> killed_queries.log )' >> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root"
ssh -t -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$db "grep -q -F '* * * * * ( sleep 30 ; cd /root && sh kill_slow_queries.sh >> killed_queries.log )' /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root || echo ' * * * * * ( sleep 30 ; cd /root && sh kill_slow_queries.sh >> killed_queries.log )' >> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root"
ssh -t -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$db "grep -q -F '* * * * * ( sleep 45 ; cd /root && sh kill_slow_queries.sh >> killed_queries.log )' /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root || echo ' * * * * * ( sleep 45 ; cd /root && sh kill_slow_queries.sh >> killed_queries.log )' >> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root"
```

for the above shell script, every 15 minutes interval the query will run. But i need a help,

if the slow_query running in 2.15PM to kill queries. But this task is under running again 2.30PM again task started to kill slow_query task without complete first task.

I need help for if the first task start running and to finished the task. We want to start again for second task. Without complete the first task again not started to the second time interval.

If they have any ways. Pls tell me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution avoid using crontab. It creates a shell daemon.

daemon.sh:

```
#!/bin/ksh
#every 15 min
_DELAY=900

rm -f "${_FICSTOP}" 2>&1
if [ ${?} -ne 0 ]
then
 echo "$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S) FATAL : unable to delete stop file."
 return 1
fi

## star main loop
echo "$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S) : star daemon OK."

while [ 1 ]
do
  if [ -f "${_FICSTOP}" ]
  then
    echo "$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S) : stop file found; stopping daemon..."
    break
  fi

  #do what you need
  sleep 15 ; cd /root && sh kill_slow_queries.sh >> killed_queries.log 
  sleep 15 ; cd /root && sh kill_slow_queries.sh >> killed_queries.log 
  sleep 15 ; cd /root && sh kill_slow_queries.sh >> killed_queries.log 

  echo "  $(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S) : sleeping for ${_DELAY} seconds..."
  sleep ${_DELAY}

done

return 0
```

Then to call it:

```
export _FICSTOP=/root/stop.file ; nohup sh daemon.sh  &
```

Then to stop the daemon, you do a

```
touch /root/stop.file
```